# fatal error LNK1123: in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. Win7, 32bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The same project file is running in windows 10/Visual studio C++ 2010 Express in another PC.                 But getting error when i tried debugging it on computer with window 7/Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express(Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel)

Invoking CVTRES.exe:

machine:x86

verbose

out: "C:\Users\tce\AppData\local\Temp\lnk2730.tmp"

readonly

"Debug\app.res"

LINK: fatal error LINK1123: Failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

I tried all the possible ways which i came across online related to this error.

1. Project Properties

   > Configuration Properties -> Linker (General)-> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"
2. Project Properties
   -> Configuration Properties-> Manifest Tool (Input and Output)-> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No"
3. "cvtres.exe" only exist in in (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cvtres.exe). Its not there in my Microsoft.Net folder.
4. I tried installing Visual Studio service pack 1 but getting error.
5. Update: Tried repairing/uninstalling completely MS VS2010 c++ and then installing it back.                           the problem still persists! Help!